# work around for JSON.parse on large data set causing oom

Tags: javascript, react-native

Working on a project where I make an API call and get back compressed data. I then uncompress that data into a string. This string is in JSON format, and can be made into the desired JSON object with JSON.parse(data). However some of the data is quite large, and JSON.parse runs out of memory. I am looking for a workaround to parse this string into an object in a way where I don't run into a memory issue.

I have looked into streams, but have not been able to get a solution working with that.

Code goes something like this:

```
let data = apiCall() //returns base64 encoded data
let stringData = decryptData(data) //returns a string of JSON data
return makeJSONObject(stringData) //return JSONObject (what is needed)
```

Comment: Well, if it overflows heap memory, then probably there is nothing you can do unless you can allocate more memory for the program. 
If you don't need the whole object (eg you only need to read it to N levels deep), then you can pass `reviver` function as a second arg to JSON.parse - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter, implement some logic there to stop parsing when you reach certain point

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked in my case.

Because the issue was it was a large array of JSON objects getting parsed I was able to split up the string based on a deliminator, parse the smaller JSON object then add it to the array.

```
let cursor = 0;
let arr = [];
while (cursor !== -1) {
    let substring = "";
    //Get the start and end indexes of the object
    let start = returnValue.indexOf("{", cursor);
    let end = returnValue.indexOf("}", start) + 1;
    cursor = end;
    //If one of the indexes is -1 it will not be a complete object so break.
    if (cursor === -1 || start === -1 || end === -1) break;
    //get the substring of the object
    substring = returnValue.substring(start, end);
    //If there are more than 2 opening braces before the first closing brace we have a nested object
    if (substring.split("{").length > 2) {
        //Increase the end point of our substring till we have the same amount of opening braces as closing braces
        while (substring.split("{").length > substring.split("}").length) {
            end = returnValue.indexOf("}", end) + 1;
            cursor = end;
            substring = returnValue.substring(start, end);
        }
    }
    //add the parsed smaller object to our array of objects
    arr.push(JSON.parse(substring));
}
```

This solution appears to actually increase the speed of JSON parsing even for the instances where it was not running into a memory issue, but that may just be with the objects I was working with and not something that will happen all the time.